# C++ Basic Double Pointer Passing

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm sure this has been asked before but searching "c++" "pointer" "function" "array" gets me nowhere.

I have some stuff declared in main that looks like this:

```
struct point{
    float x;
    float y;
    int m;
    float points[10];
    point *next;
};
struct neighbor{
    float dist;
    point *pt;
};
neighbor **candidate = NULL;
```

And I want to pass "candidate" to a function such that I can do:

```
candidate = new neighbor*[10];
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
     candidate[i] = new neighbor;
```

Fill it with various data and then exit the function without using a return statement (this is important because I'm using boost threads which can't use a function other than void) and have the main function be able to see the changes the function did.

Sorry this is so basic but I what I think is right isn't working and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Accept a reference:

```
void fun(neighbor **& candidate);
```

Or a pointer:

```
void fun(neighbor *** candidate);
```

There's almost zero reason to ever need double pointer indirection in C++.  You're almost certainly not leveraging the language to its best.